# How to handle objectNotFoundExcetion at service layer

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have two methods at service layer in springs MVC. In one method i am throwing ObjectNotFoundExcetion with my own reason when my record not found. I am calling this method from the first method. In first method I have declared try catch for it and have further code. But once i get the ObjectNotFoundException, the whole transaction rolls back. Hence I am not able to do further processing. Why is the transaction rolling back at service layer ?

```
public void foo() {
   try {
       boo();
   } catch(ObjectNotFoundException e) {

   }
   // further code.
}

public void boo() throws ObjectNotFoundException 
{ 
  if () {
  } else {
      throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Record not found");
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing which makes transaction roll back?

Comment: I am trying to catch the exception at service layer in the foo method. So that even if I get that exception, I can avoid it and go ahead with other processing.

Comment: But dont no why the transaction is rolling back at the end even when I have handled the exception.

Comment: Check your transaction related code.

Comment: Can you paste your transaction related code for us

Comment: Is ObjectNotFoundException extending RuntimeException class? May we see the definition of ObjectNotFoundException class. Thanks.

Comment: Yes ObjectNotFoundException class is extending RuntimeException.public class ObjectNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

 public ObjectNotFoundException() {
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(String message) {
  super(message);
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(Throwable cause) {
  super(cause);
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
  super(message, cause);
 }

}

Comment: public class ObjectNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

 public ObjectNotFoundException() {
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(String message) {
  super(message);
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(Throwable cause) {
  super(cause);
 }

 public ObjectNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
  super(message, cause);
 }

}